# How to define PRIMARY KEY in azure cosmosdb arm template

Tags: azure, cassandra, azure-cosmosdb, azure-rm-template, azure-cosmosdb-cassandra-api

is it possible to define PRIMARY key in azure cosmosdb cassandra arm template ?

Let's say I have next table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo
(
 id text
 name test
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

And my ARM template:

```json
"schema":{
 "columns":[
   {
   "name":"id",
   "type":"text"
   }   
  ],
  "partitionKeys":[
    {"name":"id"} // how to define primary key ?
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primary key in Cassandra consists of one or more partition columns, and zero or more clustering columns.  In ARM templates they are defined as `partitionKeys` and `clusterKeys` arrays of objects. Here is the example from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/manage-cassandra-with-resource-manager):

```
"partitionKeys": [
    { "name": "machine" },
    { "name": "cpu" },
    { "name": "mtime" }
],
"clusterKeys": [
    {
      "name": "loadid",
      "orderBy": "asc"
    }
]
```

Comment: Useful link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/cassandra-partitioning